# express-session not saving cookie in browser

Tags: passport.js, express-session, passport-local

I've spent a few hours looking through stackoverflow questions about this topic but still haven't been able to get cookies working. I'm using passport, passport-local, and express-session. When a user logs in I'm not seeing any cookies created in google chrome even though they should be. All the lines below I've tried commenting and uncommenting, changing true to false and vice versa, etc and nothing has worked. The frontend is running on port 3000 and the express backend on 8080.

server.js

```
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:3000'}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.set("trust proxy", 1);
app.use(session({
  secret: secret.COOKIE_SECRET,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: false, maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'none' },
}));

passport.use(new LocalStrategy( ... ));

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  console.log(`serialize user ${user.user_id}`);
  process.nextTick(function () {
    done(null, user.user_id);
  });
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user_id, done) {
  const user = { 'user_id': user_id };
  console.log(`deserialize user ${user_id}`);
  process.nextTick(function () {
    done(null, user);
  });
});

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

queries.js

```
const login = (request, response) => {
  const { username, password } = request.body;
  // ... excluded code
  passport.authenticate('local', { session: true }, (err, user, info) => {
    if (user) {
      request.login(user, function (err) {
        console.log(request.user) // this prints the user correctly
        console.log(response.user) // this prints undefined
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        response.status(200).json(user);
      });
    }
  // ... excluded code
  })(request, response);
};
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions for what I can do.